# Can the QGIS spatial index be used to evaluate points contained in multiple polygons of shapefile layers using PyQGis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, spatial-index

I want to use the **spatial index** of QGIS to improve the performance in the spatial query of multiple points in multiple polygons, both are shapefiles, but has not given me good results in execution time.

The execution time is slower than a sequential algorithm with a for loop using the QgsGeometry methods (even separating the spatial index creation time).

On the other hand, the result when querying, the amount of polygons contained in polygons, of two Shapefile layers, the result is as expected and the execution time is in tenths of a second.

Is this a limitation of the QGIS spatial index (QgsSpatialIndex) or am I implementing it wrong for the case of points? here is the code

```
import time

cliente=pry.mapLayersByName('cliente')[0] # points layer
parcelas=pry.mapLayersByName('parcela')[0] # polygon layer
campoP=parcelas.fields().field('id') #field to identify the polygon

#time to create spatial index
tiempo_inicialCIE = time.time()
index = QgsSpatialIndex() # Spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex(cliente.getFeatures())
duracionCIE=time.time()-tiempo_inicialCIE

dic3=[]    # list storing the result, id and number of points contained
lisIds=[]  # list of ids returned by the spatial index
tiempo_inicialIE = time.time()
for i in parcelas.getSelectedFeatures():
    bbx=i.geometry().boundingBox()
    for j in cliente.getFeatures():
        listIds=index.intersects(bbx)
    cv=0
    for c in listIds:
        if i.geometry().contains(cliente.getFeature(c).geometry()):# Evaluate intersecting features
            cv=cv+1
    if cv > 0:
        dic3.append([i[campoP.name()],cv])
               
duracionIE=time.time()-tiempo_inicialIE
```

**Note:** I have already optimized the process using other libraries and reduced the execution time for all entities from  +20 minutes to 4.5 seconds. But I would prefer to do it with PyQGis since it is for a PlugIn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QgsSpatialIndex()` in combination with a geometry engine. I think this will give you the best available performance.

Below I have adapted your code to give an example of their usage.

```
import time

pry = QgsProject().instance()
cliente = pry.mapLayersByName('cliente')[0] # points layer
parcelas = pry.mapLayersByName('parcela')[0] # polygon layer

tiempo_inicial = time.time()

#create spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex(cliente.getFeatures())

dic3 = []# list storing the result, id and number of points contained

for i in parcelas.getSelectedFeatures():
    engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(i.geometry().constGet())
    engine.prepareGeometry()
    candidate_ids = index.intersects(i.geometry().boundingBox())
    req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(candidate_ids)
    cv = 0
    for c in cliente.getFeatures(req):
        if engine.contains(c.geometry().constGet()):# Evaluate intersecting features
            cv += 1
    if cv > 0:
        dic3.append([i['id'],cv])
               
duracion = time.time()-tiempo_inicial
print('Finished in {} seconds'.format(duracion))
#print(dic3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know the createGeometryEngine I will check it out, immediately :)

Comment: you are right @ben-w, a better performance was generated, it was reduced from 44 minutes with an algorithm without spatial index to 9.6 seconds with your script, however, I still think that there is a limitation in QGIS, applying shapely in the console and its spatial index I have managed to reduce up to 4.5 seconds.